# Why can't call the installed Pillow module in virtual environment directory?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, installation-package

Create an `ai` virtual environment:

```
pyton3.11 -m  venv ai
```

Install module in virtual environment:

```
cd  ai
python3.11 -m pip install Pillow
python3.11
Python 3.11.0rc2 (main, Jul 21 2023, 09:39:42) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
import Pillow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pillow'
```

The Pillow was installed in `/home/debian/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages`,why `python3.11 -m pip install Pillow` can't install the module `Pillow` inside `ai/lib/python3.11/site-packages`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ModuleNotFoundError%3A+No+module+named+Pillow

Answer (score 2):

The import name for Pillow is `PIL`.  Instead of `import Pillow`, use:

```
import PIL
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that before pip install, you should activate venv ai.
You just only create venv ai, but it is not activated.

```
source ai/bin/activate
```

It will be needed before pip install.

Answer (score -1):

Enable the virtual environment and import `PIL`:

```
debian@debian:~/ai$ source  bin/activate
(ai) debian@debian:~/ai$ python3.11 -m pip install Pillow
Collecting Pillow
  Using cached Pillow-10.0.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (3.4 MB)
Installing collected packages: Pillow
Successfully installed Pillow-10.0.0

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.2.2 -> 23.2.1
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
(ai) debian@debian:~/ai$ python3.11
Python 3.11.0rc2 (main, Jul 21 2023, 09:39:42) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import  Pillow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pillow'
>>> import  PIL
>>>
```